# how to split the strings and store it into different row

Tags: postgresql, format, substring

i have table name as res_schedule.In that table i have field as sq_name_new1.
the values inside that field is as follows:

```
sq_name_new1
Gawade & Sushil & Arvind(Ramchandra Ankush Gawade,Arvind     Harishchandra More,Sushil Kailas Shinde)
Arvind / Krishna / Somnath(Somnath Gopinath Londhe,Arvind     Harishchandra More,Krishna Shesha Devadiga)
Deshmukh/Arvind BBS(new)(Arvind     Harishchandra More,Sanjay Dnyaneshwar Deshmukh)
```

so After spliting it i want the result as:

```
Ramchandra Ankush Gawade Arvind     Harishchandra More Sushil Kailas Shinde Somnath Gopinath Londhe Arvind     Harishchandra More Krishna Shesha Devadiga Arvind     Harishchandra More Sanjay Dnyaneshwar Deshmukh
```

That is it should remove the initial part from the record and split the value by storing it into one by one different row.
so for this i have used the function like :

```
unnest(string_to_array(substring(res_scheduledjobs.sq_name_new1,'\((().*)\)'),','))
```

but it is not splitting the value properly.this function did the work for the record:

```
 Deshmukh/Arvind BBS(new)(Arvind     Harishchandra More,Sanjay Dnyaneshwar Deshmukh)
```

as:

```
sq_name_new1
new)(Arvind     Harishchandra More
Sanjay Dnyaneshwar Deshmukh
```

means it is not neglecting `'new)('` this part.
so what can i do,so that it will also neglect the `'new)('`  same as it did for others.

awaiting for your response.
please suggest me some solution.i need help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
'\(([^()]*)\)[^)]*$'
```

instead of

```
'\((().*)\)'
```

as regexp pattern.